Queryset needs to be custom sorted into dictonary
can I have sort my queryset in custom order. By custom I mean for every ten products I receive, the first two should be featured (set to true), while the remaining eight should be unfeatured. This pattern should be repeated for each set of ten products and saved to a dictionary. The dictionary should save the data in the format of 'id':'rank'. if is_featured is same look at rank.The database should be hited one time.
    Product.objects.all().order_by('rank', '-created').values('is_featured', 'id', 'rank')


  <EavQuerySet [{'is_featured': True, 'id': 19, 'rank': -20241209}, {'is_featured': True, 'id': 18, 'rank': -20241209}, 
        {'is_featured': True, 'id': 17, 'rank': -20241209}, {'is_featured': True, 'id': 16, 'rank': -20241209}, {'is_featured': True, 'id': 15, 'rank': -20241209}, 
        {'is_featured': False, 'id': 14, 'rank': -20241209}, {'is_featured': False, 'id': 13, 'rank': -20241209}, {'is_featured': False, 'id': 12, 'rank': -20241209}, {'is_featured': False, 'id': 11, 'rank': -20241209}, 
        {'is_featured': False, 'id': 10, 'rank': -20241209}, {'is_featured': False, 'id': 9, 'rank': -20241209}, {'is_featured': False, 'id': 8, 'rank': -20241209}, {'is_featured': True, 'id': 7, 'rank': -20241206}, 
    {'is_featured': True, 'id': 6, 'rank': -20241206}, {'is_featured': False, 'id': 1, 'rank': -20241128}, {'is_featured': True, 'id': 4, 'rank': -20241128}, 
    {'is_featured': False, 'id': 5, 'rank': 0}, {'is_featured': False, 'id': 2, 'rank': 0}, {'is_featured': False, 'id': 3, 'rank': 0}]>


So what is score?

sorry I meant rank. edited

But that is then the "new" rank?

no must keep an old rank

Just process the items by splitting these in two iterators after fetching the data, so:
from itertools import groupby, zip_longest
from operator import attrgetter

products = Product.objects.order_by('is_featured', 'rank', '-created')
items = {k: list(vs) for k, vs in groupby(products, attrgetter('is_featured'))}
featured = items.get(True, ())
featured = [featured[n : n + 2] for n in range(0, len(featured), 2)]
unfeatured = items.get(False, ())
unfeatured = [unfeatured[n : n + 8] for n in range(0, len(unfeatured), 8)]

result = {
    k: k.rank
    for fe, unfe in zip_longest(featured, unfeatured, fillvalue=())
    for k in (*fe, *unfe)
}
This will make a dictionary that maps Product objects to the old rank, and in the order of first two featured ones, then eight unfeatured, then two featured, etc.

products = Product.objects.order_by('is_featured', 'rank', '-created'), after fetched data can I do with one iteration is that possible

@NodirkhujaKhamitov: I don't understand what you mean. We fetch all the products at the same time, and thus let the groupby and slicing then do the work.

I just thought it is very heavy time complexity

@NodirkhujaKhamitov: no, once the data is transferred, this runs linear.

@NodirkhujaKhamitov: can you explain why you think that?

time complexity is O(nlogn) is that right? can we make this O(n)?

or should I do something in database level to do this better?

@NodirkhujaKhamitov: no, it is linear time, we don't sort at the Python level, groupby looks for "chunks", it doesn't first sort, it only checks if the "key" is still the same. So if we assume dictionaries have a constant lookup time (which is nearly always the case), it runs linear.
